# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script

Tags: ssl, nginx, service-worker, lets-encrypt

Hey Guys Anyone Used Service Workers here ?
So As we know it works Either with localhost or domain with https ,
I tried to install Let'sEncrypt in my local computer
and added a self Signed Certificate
But Service Workers still doesn't work

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.`

Any Idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Your issue is not clear. You want to use your computer as a server to serve content for another devices, or do you just want to test this locally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188759/uncaught-in-promise-domexception-failed-to-register-a-serviceworker-for-scop

Answer (score -2):

You can use ngrok for secure https tunnel to redirect to localhost.

It will resolve the issue you are facing.

https://ngrok.com/