# "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope" - The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, service-worker

we developed a web app at script.google.com, that uses AppsScript.
We try to convert this in a progressive web app (PWA). For this I added a
`<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json.html">`, which throws no error.

But we get an error for the following code, that should load the service worker in the script tag part of the index.html:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
   {
     window.addEventListener('load', () => {
       navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js.html')
       .then((reg) => {
         console.log('Service worker registered.', reg);
         });
       });
   }
```

I already tried it in the above code with `/service-worker.js` instead of `/service-worker.js.html`, but still get the same error in the javascript console of the current Google Chrome browser, which is:

**The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('
') with script ('
'): The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.**

Currently we are not sure, if it's wanted by Google to turn a web app hosted at script.google.com into a progressive web app?

Does anybody have a solution for turning a web app at script.google.com into a progressive web app without the mentioned error messages in the Google Chrome browser?

I assume, that this error is by design, because **Google sends every html page** with it's **own code**, that included our own written code **in an iframe**, that is not allowed to access the original html where it is embedded.
Maybe I am wrong?